# LinkedList causes exception but not sure why?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, polymorphism, binary-tree

this code is similar to a couple of posts already on here, however I'm having a unique issue. The linked list is causing an exception when trying to insert an object. There should be 5 players, each with a different number of weapons, each weapon having a different number of rounds. I'm at a loss. Please help!

**LinkedList.h**

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList {
public:
 T *first;
 LinkedList();
 ~LinkedList();
 inline bool IsEmpty();
 inline void Insert(T *);
 void Display()const; 
 T *Find(const int key)const; 
 T *Delete(); 
 T *Delete(const int key); 
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
      first = 0;
}

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){

}

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::IsEmpty(){
     return (first == 0);
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::Insert(T * newLink){
     newLink->next = first; //exception break highlights here
     first = newLink;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::Display()const {
               T *current = first;
               while (current != 0) {
                 current->Display();
                 current = current->next;
               }
}

template <class T>
T *LinkedList<T>::Find(const int key)const {
               T *current = first;
               while (current->data != key){
                  if (current->next == 0)
                      return 0;
                  else
                      current = current->next;
               }
               return current;
}

template <class T>
T *LinkedList<T>::Delete() {
              T *temp = first;
              first = first->next;
              return temp;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
class Player:public GameObject
{
public:
Player* leftChild;
Player* rightChild;
LinkedList<Weapon>* weapons;
Player();
~Player();
void Display();
bool operator != (const Player&);
bool operator <(const Player&);
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
Player::Player()
{
leftChild = 0;
rightChild = 0;
}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::Display()
{
}

bool Player::operator<(const Player& player)
{
if (this->instances < player.instances)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

bool Player::operator!=(const Player& player)
{
if (instances == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main()
{   
Player *players[4];
players[0] = new Player();
players[1] = new Player();
players[2] = new Player();
players[3] = new Player();
players[4] = new Player();
players[0]->weapons->Insert(new Weapon(1));
}
```

Hopefully I've included everything. I have no idea what I have done wrong, or where to go from here.

Comment: What does `weapons` point to in a newly constructed `Player`? (Followup question: why is it a pointer?)

Comment: "Hopefully I've included everything" Actually you included too much. I am pretty sure that 90% of the code is not relevant to the exception. On the other hand you included too little, because you do not tell us what is the exception.

Comment: he does tell sth about the exception in his code ...
//exception break highlights here

Comment: Beyond the answers below, I'd like you to count how many pointers you declared `players` to hold in `main()` (ans:4). Now count how many you're stuffing in to that array (ans:5). That alone invokes *undefined behavior*, even if you "fix" the indeterminate `weapons` pointer issue.

Comment: I thought 0 counted as a place? so players[4] would actually be 5 places?

Comment: @u_know_me_003 0 *is* a valid index. Its the top index where you're wrong. An array of `N` items is indexed by `[0]..[N-1]` inclusively. It is declared to hold four pointers; that is exactly how many it holds; no more.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah okay, I get it now. That's quite confusing to me!

Comment: Congratulations! You won the _Giant Wall of Code of the Year_ award!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not create a weapons object inside constructor of a Player.cpp:

```
Player::Player()
{
    leftChild = 0;
    rightChild = 0;
    weapons = new LinkedList<Weapon>;
}
```

You could also make the weapons collection non-pointer field it would be easier in management for you. Also consider using STL collection instead of your own (less risk of nasty exceptions)...

**Edit:**
Yeah MrYellow is right. Try to use `list<Weapon>` instead of your `LinkedList<Weapon>` which implements nice `push_front` and `push_back` methods, also try to avoid pointers unless you really see the purpose of their usage...

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed that completely. All I have to do know is figure out how to give them weapons, rounds, individual id's and display it to the console. Hopefully i'll be able to figure it out :) Again. Thank You!

Comment: This is not your only problem!! When I look into your Insert Method of your LinkedList class, my head starts aching. You want to insert a newLink object and set the next item of this new item to first?!? and after that, your first becomes the newLink object(this would be valid for the first item you insert, but what is with the 2nd object etc.)? That is not a linked list at all!

Comment: @Mr.Yellow I honestly don't know enough about c++ to know there was anything wrong with it. the LL, stack and tree files are provided, I just have to make the rest work... somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `weapons` also. For example in the Player() constructor:

```
Player::Player() {
    leftChild = 0;
    rightChild = 0;
    weapons = new LinkedList<Weapon>;
}
```

Otherwise `players[0]->weapons` points to invalid pointer, which causes the exception.